# Slow query with where on joined column

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I tried to combine 2 queries into 1 by using JOINs

```php
// Query 1
$entity = \DB::select("
    SELECT memo_id 
    FROM entities 
    WHERE entity_type = 4 
    AND entity_id = '".$entity_nr."' 
    LIMIT 1
");
$memo = \DB::select("
    SELECT memo 
    FROM memos 
    WHERE id = '".$entity[0]->memo_id."' 
    LIMIT 1
");

// Query 2
$memo = \DB::select('
    SELECT memo
    FROM memos 
    JOIN entities ON "memos"."id" = "entities"."memo_id" 
    WHERE "entities"."entity_type" = 4
    AND "entities"."entity_id" IN (?)
    LIMIT 1
', [$entity_nr]);
```

The 2 query's of `Query 1` are done in less than a second. `Query 2` takes several seconds. If i remove the where clause of `Query 2` it executes fast. Using `AND "entities"."entity_id" = ?` did'nt helped as well.

Howto solve this?

#### **UPDATE 2020-09-27**

Refactoring my question. Hopes this makes it clearer. Expected output is to get the memo. There is always only 1 possible match. In the example code im not checking for existence of the result, because it doesn't really add something to the question.

Database which im using is "Actian Zen database".

**Table structure**

```php
//////////////////////////
// Table: "entity_memo" //
//////////////////////////

CREATE TABLE "entity_memo" (
    "entity_type" SMALLINT,
    "entity_id" CHAR(15),
    "memo_id" INTEGER
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "key0" ON "entity_memo" ( "entity_type", "entity_id", "memo_id" );
CREATE INDEX "key1" ON "entity_memo" ( "memo_id", "entity_type", "entity_id" );

//////////////////////////
// Table: "memos"       //
//////////////////////////

CREATE TABLE "memos" (
    "id" INTEGER,
    "memo" LVAR(32002) 
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "key0" ON "memos" ( "id" );
```

**Option 1 (= fast, but 2 queries)**

```php
$entity_type = 1;
$entity_id = 'ABC123456';

$entity = \DB::select('
    SELECT memo_id
    FROM entity_memo 
    WHERE entity_type = ? 
    AND entity_id = ? 
    LIMIT 1
    ', [$entity_type, $entity_id]
);

$memo = \DB::select('
    SELECT memo
    FROM memos 
    WHERE id = ? 
    LIMIT 1
    ', [$entity[0]->memo_id]
);

return $memo[0]->memo;
```

**Option 2 (= slow, but 1 query only)**

```php
$entity_type = 1;
$entity_id = 'ABC123456';

$memo = \DB::select('
    SELECT memo
    FROM memos 
    JOIN entity_memo ON "memos"."id" = "entity_memo"."memo_id" 
    WHERE "entity_memo"."entity_type" = ?
    AND "entity_memo"."entity_id" = ?
    LIMIT 1
    ', [$entity_type, $entity_id]
);

return $memo[0]->memo;
```

Comment: I honestly don't see how that query can work at all since you're using the wrong type of quotes around the table and column names. In MySQL, double quotes are for values. To encode table and column names (which is only necessary if those names clash with reserved keywords in MySQL), you need to use back ticks. Or is there some "Laravel magic" that fixes that for you?

Comment: Btw, why are you using `IN` instead of `=` in the last query?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Because i read an article that it maybe would speed the query

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson tbh, im not using MySQL, but a rather unknown type of DB (im not in control of the DB structure), but i can translate the corresponding answers to my needs :)

Comment: Since it isn't MySQL, I've removed that tag. It's important that we know what DB you're using, or we can't help with any specifics at all, which this question most likely would need.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The `join` conditions look quite suspicious.  I don't understand what `unique_id` is.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I will add some sample data later today. I changed around some keys to clear it up, else it would be a mess. I changed `unique_id` again. I haven't designed the DB, which is really poor designed and i cant change it. The indexes are set correctly though.

Comment: Question is updated

Answer (score -1):

It will be look simpler, if you write it without JOINs.

```
SELECT ent.unique_id, mem.memo
  FROM entities ent, memos mem
 WHERE ent.unique_id = mem.unique_id
   AND ent.entity_type = 4
   AND ent.entity_id = '".$entity_nr."'
```

But the cause of query working slow is in tables itself. You should to add indexes to PK and FK columns for query to work faster.

Comment: 1. Don't manually add the values in your query like that. 2. Using JOIN is the correct way to JOIN tables.

Comment: The values are safe though, they are created programaticly

Comment: How is this not a JOIN? It seems to be just using old syntax.